# Can I use my unlocked Samsung Galaxy J2(J200G) 4G VoLTE India phone in USA?

Tags: usa, cellphones

I checked my phone supports wide range of bands as mentioned on GSM Arena: [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j2-7357.php)
HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100
LTE band 1(2100), 3(1800), 5(850), 8(900), 20(800), 40(2300)

I will be travelling to Atlanta, GA via Boston and want to know if USA SIM bought from Matrix works there [USA - Matrix SIM](https://shop.matrix.in/search/products?ddlCountry=9&Country=USA)

Answer (score 1):

Your phone will work fine on HSDPA in the US, (and mostly anywhere else on the planet too) but it won't get 4G LTE service anywhere. None of the LTE bands listed are currently used by any US mobile carriers. Where you usually see "LTE" next to the signal strength, your phone will show an "H+" symbol when you have HSDPA high speed data, "3G" for 3G data (and if I read their web site correctly Matrix treat this as high speed too, even though it can be quite slow), and "EV" or "1X" for 2G data. Note that 2G is being phased out in the US, so there are places where you might have no data service at all, but if you remain in a metro area you should be fine.